# special case on Rotation matrix to Angle-axis conversion (theta is 180 degree)

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, 3d

```
Rf = np.array([[-0.032, -0.999,  0.02 ,  0.88 ],
   [-0.999,  0.031, -0.008, -0.076],
   [ 0.007, -0.02 , -1.   ,  0.409],
   [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ]])


theta = np.arccos((Rf[0,0]+Rf[1,1]+Rf[2,2]-1)/2)
kx = (Rf[2,1]-Rf[1,2])/2/np.sin(theta)
ky = (Rf[0,2]-Rf[2,0])/2/np.sin(theta)
kz = (Rf[1,0]-Rf[0,1])/2/np.sin(theta)
kxf = kx*theta
kyf = ky*theta
kzf = kz*theta

[Rf[0,3], Rf[1,3], Rf[2,3], kxf, kyf, kzf]
```

However, (Rf[0,0]+Rf[1,1]+Rf[2,2]-1)/2 = -1,

so theta is -180 degree.

np.sin(-180) equals to 0.

kx, yy, kz is undefined.

How to handle this case? and find the correct Angle-axis conversion? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToAngle/) under the singularities section.